# Uniform Random with Less Sample

Tags: random, statistics, cocos2d-x, uniform-distribution

I am working on a game AI and using some randoms for making the decisions more stochastic. I am using `cocos2d::random()`

My experiment with the current `random()` function showed that if I pick 10K samples, I get the desired result. However, in the game, it is not very possible to pick such samples and this makes the random function behave not uniform.

So, my question is whether there is a way to improve uniformity of the random function with less samples.

Here is an example how I am using the `random()` function for shooting decision:

```
if( mShouldRedecideCanShootDecision)
{
    mShouldRedecideCanShootDecision = false;

    int chance = randomInt(0, 100);

    // mistake is a floating point number in [0, 1] range
    int upTo = std::roundf( mistake * 100.f );

    mCanShoot = true;
    if(chance < upTo)
    {
        mCanShoot = false;
    }
}
```

`randomInt()` function based on `cocos2d::random()`:

```
// Max is inclusive
int randomInt(int min, int max)
{
    if(min > max)
    {
        std::swap(min, max);
    }

    return min + ( cocos2d::random() % (max - min + 1) );
}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you really want. It sounds very informal. Maybe you are talking about variance-reduction techniques or quasi-random sequences. But it's hard to guess.

Comment: Are you talking about modulo bias in randomInt()?